# datalife engine - upload file to the server and the file name cut down

Tags: php, file-upload, datalife-engine

I use Data life engine CMS and when I upload a file to the server the file names are cut.

For example:
I upload a file to the server with the name:

> php-fusion-v7-nusirasinek.lt-template

and after the upload the file name is cut like this:

> 1484383015_-fusion-v7-nusirasinek.lt-template

How can I keep the full name?

> 1484383015_php-fusion-v7-nusirasinek.lt-template

Comment: Give more details on specific version you use

Comment: Problem solved!